# Singular homology of discrete space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a space with discrete topology. How to calculate singular homology of $X$, if:

a)  $|X|$ is finite

b) $|X|$ is countable

c) $|X|$ is uncountable.

For $|X|=1$ it is obvious, but I have problem with $|X|>1$. I think that b) and c) would be the same.

Comment: If X is a finite set then $H_{o}(X)$ should be $\mathbb{Z}^{|X|}$ and all higher $H_{i}$ should be trivial because any higher CW complex can only map to a point by connectivity. For case (b) , (C) $H_{0}$ should be the direct product: $\prod_{|X|} \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Parts b) abd c) of the comment by @DBS are false.

Comment: Georges Elencwajg is right: the homology should be $\sum_{|X|} \mathbb{Z}$ and the cohomology would be $\prod_{|X|} \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a ring $R$ the result in all three cases is $$H_0(X;R)=R^{(X)}=\oplus _{x\in X}R$$ Indeed, all zero-chains are cycles : $S_0(X;R)=Z_0(X;R)$, and all zero-boundaries are zero:  $B_0(X;R)=0$, so that $H_0(X;R)=S_0(X;R)=\oplus _{x\in X}R$.
Similarly, for $q\gt 0$ we have $$H_q(X;R)=\oplus _{x\in X}H_q(\{x\};R)=0$$ The (trivial) key-point is that every singular $q$-simplex $\Delta_q\to X$ must have as image a single point $x\in X$.